# XSLT nested conditionals - how to do this

Tags: xslt, nested, conditional-statements

I'm quite new to xslt

I have the following xslt snippet (pseudo'ed for clarity):

```
<xsl:for-each select="fields/field">
  <xsl:if test="field=someThing">
    <div>
      <!--some content output-->
      <!--here by doing-->
      <!--some complex stuff-->
    </div>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But based on value of field from loop, I optionally want to do some other stuff before the closing div.

So (armed with shiny new xsl book) I thought I could do something like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="fields/field">
  <xsl:if test="field=someThing">
    <div>
      <!--some content output-->
      <!--here by doing-->
      <!--some complex stuff-->
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="field=someThingSpecific">
        <div>
        <!--process some additional-->
        <!--stuff here-->
        </div>
        <!--then close div-->
        </div>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <!--nothing to do here-->
        <!--just close the div-->
        </div>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But it blows up.

Apparently because the closing div has moved into the conditional xsl:choose block

So 2 questions really:

why doesnt it work as is?

how can I achieve my objective?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's blowing up because your XSLT isn't well-formed. When you open the first `div` outside of the `xsl:choose`, you have to close it outside the `xsl:choose`.

Also, if you don't need to do anything in your `xsl:otherwise`, just do another `xsl:if`:

```
<xsl:for-each select="fields/field">
    <xsl:if test="field=someThing">
        <div>
            <!--some content output-->
            <!--here by doing-->
            <!--some complex stuff-->
            <xsl:if test="field=someThingSpecific">
                <div>
                    <!--process some additional-->
                    <!--stuff here-->
                </div>
            </xsl:if>
            <!--then close div-->
        </div>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: yea I just woke up with a 'durrhhh moment'. thanks for clarifing